# How can I manually unload an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got a React frontend using a NodeJS backend application running as an App Service in Azure.  And I'm troubleshooting that it doesn't work properly to wake up / load the backend application after it has been unloaded due to inactivity.

According to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/14776) GitHub issue, the App Service is not unloaded before 20 minutes of inactivity.

Since it would be very ineffective to have to wait 20 minutes for the app to be unloaded over and over while troubleshooting my problem, I would like to manually trigger the App Service to be unloaded.  Either using the CLI, an API, a menu option in Azure or something else.

How can I manually trigger Azure to unload an App Service?

Comment: why not use Always-on?

Comment: Because Always-on is not available on Free tier.  You need at least Basic payment plan.

Comment: This question is being discussed on Meta: [What can I do when I feel my question has been closed for an incorrect reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405284/4642212).

Comment: @rene At first I thought it was because op was not clear about the principle of iis's lazy loading of webapp, so I didn't understand his requirement very well. The following answer has been tested and can help op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you kill `w3wp.exe`, I think this is the same function as clicking the recovery on the iis physical server. The process is killed and a new `w3wp.exe` process will be regenerated when the website is revisited, which can be distinguished by pid.

**Tips:**

*It's just that the test effect is similar, not that the recycle on iis is also a kill process to achieve this function.*

[image]

Step 1.  Open `SCM` site.

Step 2.  Click Process explorer.

[image]

Step 3.  Right click `w3wp.exe`, not `scm`.

[image]

Step 4.  Then click `Kill`.

## ***Show test results:***

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked quite well and was exactly what I was looking for.  Although the UI doesn't quite look like your screenshots, there is a process explorer in Azure Portal that I could use to kill the w3wp process.  The behavior was exactly like if unloaded automatically by Azure.  Thank you!